# Heroku - installing Node.js -

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, git-clone

I have just found Heroku and am following their tutorial to install a nodejs application here.https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prepare-the-app

But I ran into some problems when trying to do "git clone"

I have installed the Heroku toolbar to my computer, then opened cmd.exe and was able to do "heroku login" and logged in successfully.  Error started with me trying to clone the app with:
git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git

```
>Error: unable to create file index.js (permission denied)
>clone succeeded but checkout failed
>unable to check out working tree
```

The following steps also created errors so I could not advance further with the tutorial:

inspect with "git status"

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

retry chekcout with "git checkout -f HEAD"

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

cd node-js-getting-started

> The system cannot find the path specified

Please let me know where I went wrong

Comment: It looks like a permissions error, doesn't it? Where on your filesystem did you try to run `git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git`?

Comment: @Chris - I ran git clone here:  C:WINDOWS\system32

Comment: That's probably not a good place to run `git clone`. Windows operating system files live in `system32`, and users should generally stay out of that directory. This might explain your error. What if you try running the `clone` command from a personal directory, e.g. ``C:\Users\Danh\Documents\``? It almost always makes sense to work with source code in a personal directory.